# .htaccess 301 redirect all directories to parent

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have a strange issue happening after a WordPress Migration.

After setting up a new domain, I used:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to redirect all blog posts to the new domain.  This works perfect.

I now found some urls such as

http://www.olddomain.com/blog/directory/file/ that I want to send to http://www.newdomain.com/blog/directory/

Directory is a variable and file is a variable.

Is it possible to create an htaccess that keeps my original Rule, but also creates another rule to handle the the file redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)/? http://www.newdomain.com/blog/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will keep your original rule and will rewrite `http://www.olddomain.com/blog/directory/file/` to `http://www.newdomain.com/blog/directory/`

The `/?` means that the last `/` is optional i.e.  it will redirect `http://www.olddomain.com/blog/directory/file/` and `http://www.olddomain.com/blog/directory/file` to `http://www.newdomain.com/blog/directory/`

Comment: No, you're going to have to put the more selective match _ahead_ of the less selective match.

Comment: Doesn't $1 just copy what it found?  For example RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/(.*)/? http://www.newdomain.com/blog/ [R=301,L] works great, to just go to the blog, but I would prefer it to go to the parent directory.  When I keep $1 in, it is just redirecting the exact same as the other line is.